# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable python 3.2.5

Tags: python, typeerror

What's wrong with my code? I keep getting the error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I do not understand why I keep getting that error, when everything is defined and is forced to a str when needed, if not more than needed.

```
import time

hallNumber = ""

if hallNumber == str(1):
    print('You find a window')
else :
    print('You find what you think is a door')

def dispIntro():
        text_file = open("E:\Intro_game_develop\projects\project_one\intro.txt", 'r')
        whole_thing = text_file.read()
        print(whole_thing)
        text_file.close()

def chooseHall():
    hall = ''
    while hall != '1' and hall != '2':
            print('Which hall do you choose to go down? 1, or 2')
            hall = input()

    return hall


def checkHall(chosenHall):
        print('You walk down the hall...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('You walk towards the light...')
        time.sleep(1)

        print('You reach out for it and...')
        time.sleep(1)
##hallNumber = ""
##
##if hallNumber == str(1):
##    print('You find a window')
##else :
##    print('You find what you think is a door')


def chosenPath(hallNumber):
    print("I'm in chosenPath")
    path = str(hallNumber())
    if path == str(hallNumber(1)):
            text_file = open("E:\Intro_game_develop\projects\project_one\window.txt", 'r')

            whole_thing = text_file.read()

            print(whole_thing)

            text_file.close()

    else:
             text_file = open("E:\Intro_game_develop\projects\project_one\door.txt",'r')

             whole_thing = text_file.read()

             print(whole_thing)

             text_file.close()

             return path
```

Comment: what is `hallNumber(1)` supposed to do?

Comment: or even just `hallNumber()` on the line above it, for that matter...

Comment: you set hallNumber to a string and then you call it hallNumber() but it is not a function, can't call a string like a funciton

Comment: Supply the actual code that runs when you run the script..

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
hallNumber = "foo"
path = str(hallNumber())
```

On line 1, `hallNumber` is set to a string.

On line 2, `hallNumber`, which is a string, is invoked like a function with `hallNumber()`, and then the output of that function is cast to a string with `str()`.  But `hallNumber` isn't a callable function - it's a string.

Hence the `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.